# Using Expansion Support for Android in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've got problem with using ExpansionDownloader for Android / Xamarin. I am trying to copy file in sd\Android\obb\SampleApp.SampleApp\ directory file:

- patch.1.SampleApp.obb

and read it with

```
var expansionFile = ApkExpansionSupport.GetApkExpansionZipFile(this, 1, 0);
Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Debug, "Expansion files", "Files found: " + expansionFile.GetAllEntries().Count());
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="SampleApp.SampleApp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk />
    <application android:label="SampleApp" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
</manifest>
```

Problem is that in LogCat i've got information about 0 files found. Maybe I am doing something wrong or miss something important?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figure out what was going on:

- file name should be main.1.SampleApp.obb
- VS while deploying app on physical device was deleting expansion files